# How to insert 1000 rows into an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, loops, insert

I have this stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure InsertProduct
    (product_name VARCHAR2, 
     product_price int, 
     product_description varchar2) 
as
begin
    insert into PRODUCT (name, price, description, create_date) 
    values (product_name, product_price, product_description, sysdate);
end;
```

I used it to insert 1000 rows at time:

```
begin
    for insert_loop in 1..1000 loop
        InsertProduct(dbms_random.string('x', 10), DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 100000) , dbms_random.string('x', 10));
        end loop;
        commit;
end;

delete from PRODUCT;
```

but this loop adds random records, is it possible to do so to add real product records, if yes, how to do it?

Comment: That depends. Where are the records coming from? What language and/or framework is the application constructed in? Is the procedure exposed as a REST endpoint? Your procedure could work for many cases, but not for others (some frameworks won't allow you to call custom pl/sql procedures). I'm not sure anyone here can help you until you've explained more about your application, what you've already tried (with a reproducible example), and what errors you've encountered.

Comment: The real question is: "How to get *real* product names inside the database?" This questionis not answerable and has nothing to do with Oracle or any other DBMS. Moreover, program code cannot know is something *real* or not. Why do you think that product "gjngdl14525ayerlkblskfkl" is unreal?

Comment: Because you misspelled it, @astentx. Should've been "gjngdl14525ayerFkblskfkl".

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to do so to add real product records

Yes, just call your procedure 1000 times with the real data.

For example:

```sql
begin
  InsertProduct('Apple',    45, 'A red fruit');
  InsertProduct('Banana',   33, 'A yellow fruit');
  InsertProduct('Cucumber', 70, 'A green vegetable');
  InsertProduct('Date',      5, 'A brown fruit');
  commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using `FORALL`? If you have the ability to create a collection of records for the data that you want to insert, you can insert them all using one statement similar to the example below.

Using `FORALL` will also make your code perform faster since it is only 1 `INSERT` statement with all the records vs 1000 individual `INSERT` statemements.

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE product_t IS TABLE OF product%ROWTYPE;

    l_products   product_t := product_t();
BEGIN
    l_products.extend(3); --number of items we'll be creating
    l_products (1).name := 'name1';
    l_products (1).price := 1;
    l_products (1).description := 'description1';
    l_products (2).name := 'name2';
    l_products (2).price := 2;
    l_products (2).description := 'description2';
    l_products (3).name := 'name3';
    l_products (3).price := 3;
    l_products (3).description := 'description3';

    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_products.COUNT
        INSERT INTO product (name,
                             price,
                             description,
                             create_date)
             VALUES (l_products (i).name,
                     l_products (i).price,
                     l_products (i).description,
                     SYSDATE);
END;
```

If you want to see how sample data can be created, the example below will create 1500 rows of sample data. Again this will perform faster than the code you provided because it is 1 `INSERT` vs 1500 `INSERT`s that it would take using your code.

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE product_t IS TABLE OF product%ROWTYPE;

    l_products   product_t := product_t ();
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 1500
    LOOP
        l_products.EXTEND;
        l_products (i).name := DBMS_RANDOM.string ('x', 10);
        l_products (i).price := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (low => 1, high => 100000);
        l_products (i).description := DBMS_RANDOM.string ('x', 10);
    END LOOP;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_products.COUNT
        INSERT INTO product (name,
                             price,
                             description,
                             create_date)
             VALUES (l_products (i).name,
                     l_products (i).price,
                     l_products (i).description,
                     SYSDATE);
END;
```